# paramiko can't connect to ssh server

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I want to send a command over ssh with python

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect("192.168.0.62",port="22", username="username", password="password")
```

And when i run it I get this

```
  File "prog.py", line 8, in <module>
    ssh.connect("192.168.0.62",port="22", username="username", password="password")
  File "/home/rick/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 416, in connect
    self, server_hostkey_name, server_key
  File "/home/rick/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 824, in missing_host_key
    "Server {!r} not found in known_hosts".format(hostname)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server '[192.168.0.62]:22' not found in known_hosts
```

What should i do

Comment: your known host key is missing in host keys file ... add the key in file or change the mode to
`ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())`
this is not a good way during security concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's private network try adding line `ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())` 
after creation of `SSHClient`.

[AutoAddPolicy](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html#paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy) from Paramiko docs